# Loading data correctly from API with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that needs information from Redux to load from an API. I want to learn the most efficient way to deal with this situation.

To explain (simplified):

```
 class someComponent extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {data: null}
   }
   componentWillMount(){
     if(this.props.reduxstate){ //api needs reduxstate
       api(`/someroute?q1=reduxstate')
       .then((data)=>this.setState({data:data})
    }
  }

  render(){        
    return(
      <div>
        <AnotherComponentNeedingAPIData data={data} />
      </div>
    )
  }


  function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
      state.reduxstate
    }
  }
```

To be clear, the error here is that reduxstate isn't available when it hits componentWillMount so the api never loads. I am not interested in this error, just what the correct pattern should be in the above situation

I originally wrote out the various iterations I have been through with this problem. I am aware there is more than one way to solve this but I feel like I am missing the correct/simplest way to do it. The above general pattern is my preferred starting point so that I can keep the subcomponents stateless.

What I am doing wrong (and how should I think about this problem in the right way?)?

EDIT: I decided to use componentWillRecieveProps...this is fine, but it doesn't feel like the right approach as this involves loading data in two places in the component.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is `componentWillRecieveProps` as you have done, and I think it's fine. Alternatively you could dispatch the response of your api call and your component needing the api could access it via redux - but this is unnecessary if you only use the data in one place.

If your logic gets much more complicated, though, then some asynchronous redux library might be useful for extracting the implementation details from your components, like, [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).

I like redux saga, it allows you to listen to actions dispatched to redux, and then do asynchronous things like api calls, and dispatch more actions.

This way you would have your api data in the redux store too, so your component that needs the data could just connect directly with redux.

It adds some indirection, though, so I wouldn't jump to this solution straight away.

Comment: Okay, great. So the problem here is really having these two different sources of data? And the only other/next option would be to integrate with redux to bring them together?

Comment: Yeah, that's my view.

This article covers when to use redux quite well if you want to read more, it's a little inconclusive but that reflects the community as I see it:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/whats-so-great-about-redux-ac16f1cc0f8b